# Merge two apps in AppStore

Tags: app-store

Let's assume that I have got two applications:

- `A` - which is old product hard to maintain, webview-based, no-ARC, iOS 5.0 and all things that you don't want in app
- `B` - new, light version but less features

Both apps are free, and do not use any in app purchases, they gain money on ads.

From business reasons I cannot remove `A` app from the `AppStore`, and I know, that there are some users that will be using `B` version.

By the time version `B` will catch up with features of version `A` (let's call it `B'`) and old app will no longer be needed with one exception - users. I would like to replace app `A` with `B'`, is there any way to merge those two apps into one, so that `B'` version will be available for `A` and `B` users as a one app?

There is a similar question [App Store - Best way to merge a paid and free version into a free version with IAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644640/app-store-best-way-to-merge-a-paid-and-free-version-into-a-free-version-with-i) but as I understand solutions you need to force `A` app users do download `B'` and I want this process to be transparent for users.

Answer (score 1):

At the point when you finish features for app `B` cannot you release it as app `A` to appstore?

You would have to maintain 2 versions of app but basically they would be the same, just 2 apps in app store.

Comment: This is an option but I think new users could be confused them and also there is question if Apple will not reject one of those app as a duplicate. Thanks for answer!